# Testing Phoenix controllers that are in nested folders

Tags: testing, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an elixir umbrella application which contains a phoenix app and an elixir app. The app is working as expected but I am having an issue testing one of the controllers.

The tests in the file will not run when I run the tests. It looks like they are somehow being skipped in the testing process.

The controller file looks something like...

```
defmodule AppName.File.Path.NameOfController do
  def index(conn, params) do
    render(conn, "index.html")
  end
end
```

The test file is fairly simple as well and looks something like...

```
defmodule AppName.File.Path.NameOfControllerTest do
  test "GET /"the_url/I/want", %{conn: conn} do
    conn = get conn, some_path(conn, :index)
    assert html_response(conn, 200) =~ "Some html"
  end
end
```

All the tests in my project run with the exception on this one file. I thought that it might have something to do with the file path but I cannot see any reason why this would effect the test. I can also go to the endpoint when I run the application.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the file that your tests are coming from named with the ".exs" extension (as opposed to ".ex").  That has bitten me in the past.

Comment: Hey @ScottThompson, yeah the file has the `.exs` extension. Thanks for your comment, it is definitely something that is always work checking.

Answer (score 0):

`conn = get conn, some_path(conn, :index)` should be `conn = get conn, name_of_path(conn, :index)`

To get the correct path helper, Phoenix removes the trailing `Controller` and converts the name to snake case and appends `_path`.

So `NameOf` becomes `name_of`